# Django send_mail() "502 Bad Gateway" error in production

Tags: django

I need expert advice.
I have set my Django web application on Digital Ocean. It is using ubunto OS with Nginx and gunicorn. Everything working great except when it comes to send email. Everytime when I send email from my website I get "502 Bad Gateway error". I am exploring google from past three days but nothing seems to work for me.

**Note:** When I put my gmail configurations in settings.py, everything works perfect. 
I suppose there is something wrong with my domain email configurations, that are:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'golf.mywebsitebox.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

But I have thrice checked them with my domain providers and they say these configuration are correct. Now I don't know what is the cause of this problem? To whom I consult in this regard?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? Facing similar issues here.

Comment: This 465 port was closed. I contacted email providers and they suggested me port 26. Email worked on that port

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work for me. Apparently my cloud service provider blocks email ports by default so I'll have to add my domain and then raise a ticket with them.